# How to send the position value of clicked item as an Intent Extra?

Tags: android, android-intent, onclick

I have two activities, `Activity1 extends ListActivity` and `Activity2`.
I've used my own adapter for `ListActivity`.
I want to launch `Activity2` when I click one of the list item.
There's a `ImageView1` in the `Activity2`. When I click first item in the `ListActivity`, I want to set FirstImage which is located in the drawable folder to the `ImageView1` of `Activity2`.
When I click second item in the `ListActivity`, I want to replace the SecondImage which is located in the drawable folder to the ImageView1.
So, I need to send the position value of clicked item as an Intent Extra.
I'm confusing about sending position value. I also want to write with Switch-Case.
Anyone explain me?
I'm absolute beginner. 
Thanks

Home.java (Activity1)

```
public class Home extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.home);
        String [] items = new String []{"Banana","Apple","Orange","Pineapple","Lime","Papaya","Mango"};
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, items);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        //Toast.makeText(this, "You touched"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



    }
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private String [] objects;


    public CustomAdapter (Context context, String []objects){
        super(context,R.layout.row, objects);
        this.context=context;
        this.objects=objects;


    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        TextView tv= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ImageView iv= (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        tv.setText(objects[position]);
        if (objects[position].startsWith("Apple")) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple);
        }
        else if (objects[position].startsWith("Banana")) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.banana);

        }
        else if (objects[position].startsWith("Lime")) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lime);
        }
        else if (objects[position].startsWith("Mango")) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.mango);
        }
        else if (objects[position].startsWith("Orange")) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange);
        }
        else if (objects[position].startsWith("Papaya")) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.papaya);
        }
        else {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.pineapple);
        }

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Activity2 has only one ImageView

Comment: post some snippet of your code

Comment: You can make use putInt(String key, int value). Please check the below links. You will get more idea regarding it.http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-using-intents-to-pass-data-and-return-results-between-activities/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Intent` . Suppose you override the `OnListItemClick` and inside it you start `Activtity2`

```
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    intent.putExtra("pos", position);
    startActivity(intent)
  }
```

in the Activity2 `onCreate` use `getIntent();`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("pos", 0);

}
```